# itemclick event in spark tabbar?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Hallo tabbar supports item click event. However spark tabBar doesnot supports itemClick event.

is there way to listen itemclick event in SPARK TABBAR

thanks all

Comment: Nope. Use [IndexChangeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/IndexChangeEvent.html)

Comment: Spark tabar doesnot supports indexChangeEvent

Comment: Yes it does: that `change` in the MXML notation is in fact an `IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE`.

Comment: welll it doesn't dispatched each time u click on selected tabbar! right.

Comment: That's right. I've updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Spark components inheriting from ListBase no longer dispatch ItemClick events. You can use the  [IndexChangeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/IndexChangeEvent.html) event instead though. It has a property `newIndex` that tells you which is the newly selected item (or tab in this particular case).

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{dp}" change="trace('selected: ' + event.newIndex)" />
```

One big difference with the old ItemClick is that this event is only dispatched when the selected item actually changes (as opposed to whenever it is clicked). If you really want the behaviour of ItemClick back, you can create a custom ItemRenderer that dispatches an 
ItemClick event.

---

If you want to react on every click there are a few approaches. Here are two of them:

1./ Create a custom ItemRenderer that dispatches an ItemClick event.

.

```
public class TabBarButton extends ButtonBarButton {

    override public function initialize():void {
        super.initialize();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireItemClick);
    }

    private function fireItemClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        owner.dispatchEvent(new ItemClickEvent(
            ItemClickEvent.ITEM_CLICK, false, false, null, itemIndex, null, data
        ))
    }

}
```

You can now use it like this:

```
<s:TabBar id="tabBar" dataProvider="{dp}" 
          itemRenderer="net.riastar.TabBarButton" />

tabBar.addEventListener(ItemClickEvent.ITEM_CLICK, onItemClick);
```

2./ Another approach would be to just listen for any click event on the TabBar and use event.target to find the clicked tab:

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{dp}" click="trace(event.target)" />
//traces tabBar.TabBarSkin1.dataGroup.TabBarButton1
```

Note that this is a direct answer to your question, but I actually don't think you should do this. In most cases IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks, am trying dispatch event, whenever user clicks on tabbar. Change event will not support this kind of behaviour. Could you please give some more detail how does itemrender helps in adding itemclik event